# Locating Selenium xpath elements (FindElements) from a dropdown xpath

Tags: selenium, xpath, dropdown

I am trying to use driver.FindElemnts on a dropdown list to facilitate me to count elements in a dropdown. Somehow can't get the XPath working for below piece of html -

```
<select class="form-control form-control-lg ng-valid ng-dirty ng-touched" 
id="sel-customer-name" name="sel-customer">
<!---->
<option value="1: Object"> Kerry Mitchell </option>
<option value="2: Object"> David Brown </option>
<option value="3: Object"> Aaron Chai </option>
</select>
```

I used this, but seems to be wrong --

```
var elementsDropdown = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@id='sel-customer- 
name']/option[i]"));
```

any help is appreciated, thanks..!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You chose the wrong attribute value: `sel-adviser-type` instead of `sel-customer-name`.
So try this XPath:

```
//*[@id='sel-customer-name']/option
```

Or, in a full expression

```
var elementsDropdown = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@id='sel-customer-name']/option"));
```

Both will select you the three elements `option`.

Comment: Maybe, but it's been an essential one. Now the expression does work.

Comment: Changing essential parts of the question after receiving answers is disapproved by StackOverflow.

Comment: Yes it is working now, I had to take out the [i] as rightly suggested by you